# Fix Update version react use nx workspace

Tags: react-typescript

I am using @nrwl/workspace version 13.10.6, and i want to update to version 14.0.0, but wen run migrations.json, i have a bug: `Failed to run update-jest-config-extensions from @nrwl/jest. This workspace is NOT up to date!`

How to fix it

Comment: Nguyen  did you find any solution?

Comment: So, when my boss run yarn nx migrate --pakage-version --verbose, he see 2 file have error with ';' . Delete it. Project run